# Too many initializers while printing char 2D array

Tags: dev-c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

  // bool turnright(char **arr,int &x,int &y,bool &quit)
  // {}
  // bool turnright(char **arr,int &x,int &y,bool &quit)
  // {}
  // bool moveforward(char **arr,int &x,int &y,bool &quit)
 // {}
 // bool movebackward(char **arr,int &x,int &y,bool &quit)
 // {

 // }


 void print(char arr[][12])
 {
   for (int i=0;i<12;i++)
   {     
     for (int j=0;j<12;j++)
     {
       cout<<arr[i][j];
     }
     cout<<endl;
   }
 }


int main()
{
  char arr[12][12]={
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
    {'#','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','.','.','.','#'},
    {'#','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','#','#','.','#'},
    {'#','#','#','.','#','.','.','.','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','.','.','.','.','#','#','#','.','#','.','.'},
    {'#','.','.','.','.','#','#','#','.','#','.','.'},
    {'#','.','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','.','#','#','#','.','#'},
    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','#'},
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'}
  };
   // bool quit=false;
  // int Ix;
  // int IY;
  // while(!quit)
  // {
  //   moveforward();
  //   turnfight();
     //   if (!moveforward())
    //   {
    //     turnleft();
   //     if (!turnleft)
   //     {
   //       moveback();
  //       turnleft();
  //       if(!turnleft())
 //       {
  //         turnright();
 //       }
 //     }
 //   }

 // }
   print(arr); 
   }
```

I am trying to write code for traversing a maze while printing maze I am getting an error too many initiallizers although i have given number of rows and columns properly could any one please tell me where i am wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted your array initialization and see that row 11 has 13 elements which won't fit in an [12][12] array:

```
char arr[12][12]={
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
    {'#','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','.','.','.','#'},
    {'#','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','#','#','.','#'},
    {'#','#','#','.','#','.','.','.','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','.','.','.','.','#','#','#','.','#','.','.'},
    {'#','.','.','.','.','#','#','#','.','#','.','.'},
    {'#','.','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','.','#','#','#','.','#'},
    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','#'},
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'}
  };
```